# Joomla: Front-end Messages/Feedback

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5, frontend, joomla-template

Let's say a user logs onto the Joomla front-end and adds or edits an article. Right now, the user is redirected to the homepage. How do I show the user feedback like "You article has been saved" or "A new article has been created" etc.

Is there anything I need to add to my template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've found an answer.
You need to add this in your template:

`<jdoc:include type="message" />`